# Edit row in a dataset C#, it does not save

Tags: c#, dataset, row

I want to change some rows depending on a filter but it does not save the info. This is my code:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in datosingDataSet.Tables["inve"].Rows) // search whole table
{
    cc = Convert.ToInt32(dr["nsuc"].ToString());
    ff = Convert.ToInt32(dr["bod"].ToString());

    if (cc == csuc && ff == bod) // if id==2
    {
        MessageBox.Show("** SI SE HACE LA CONSULTA**", "ERROR");

        dr["estado"] = "AP"; //change the name
        //break; break or not depending on you
        dr.AcceptChanges();
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

foreach(DataRow rowp in datosingDataSet.inve.Select("nsuc = " + csuc + " and bod = " + bod)) {
    rowp.BeginEdit();
    rowp["estado"] = "AP";
    rowp.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Any of them work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: AcceptChanges() is not going to save your data. In fact, it marks everything as unmodified so that it would not cause any updates. If you are properly data binding (I can't tell if you are), you would only have to call `Update()` on an Adapter. And I think you should remove the c++ tag.

Comment: C# and C++? It looks like only C# code.

Comment: Are you using both C# and C++ code?  Some people use C# for the GUI and C++ for the core.  Which language talks to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
  ...
  foreach (DataRow dr in Ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
       dr.BeginEdit();
       dr["name"] = "Ali";
       dr.EndEdit();
  }
  Ds.AcceptChanges();
```